# Why is my color brownish while the tutorial is white?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am doing a tutorial and I am following step by step. For some reason, my GameObjects (cubes, planes, everything) appear brownish, while in the tutorial it is white. It also happened the same with a model I imported, my model was greenish/brownish, while on the tutorial it looked cleaner.

Why could this be?

The light is turned on, I tried checking shadows and moving the light direction.

Here is some sample images:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ftq7j4CivOY1-olFmAhE5RTvfErjam3h/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14Jt1eafoTSAo9UHRM53gZotuXl5FvCiy/view?usp=sharing

material data:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mvb-e4_st_NsyGY2G1ncbW-fLo3X5SxE/view?usp=sharing

directional light:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Dh2fKTdM-U3DVd0mxQ-Rx4K4hPyqW6Y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: its the directional lighting most likely it is white..

Comment: @BugFinder I thought so too, but changing it though it did change a little bit the color, there is a lot of shadow, unlike the tutorial, which is completely white. I also tried turning everything related to shadows.

Comment: The only difference I notice in your two images is that the first has a sun icon under the "Scene" tab, and the second has a lightbulb icon. It looks like the second is a more recent version? Also, did you check if your Mesh Renderer has the same settings?

Comment: @nbura Yes, mine is Unity 2019 and the other one is Unity 2018, but the sun and lightbulb do the same. Also I did check all the settings at the right, they are exactly the same. I also tried restarting everything. I didn't realize that it was brownish until today. When I first installed Unity and started the tutorial, it was exactly the same (different versions though). When I imported the model, it was brownish/greenish I never knew why. And now it's like this....I am not even sure what I touched. I don't remember modifying anything in any tutorial other than importing assets.

Comment: I don't know what to think... do they appear differently in Game view as well, or just Scene?

Comment: Either your lighting settings changed or you are using a different material.  can't tell because for some reason you show the full editor window in 1 screenshot, and a cropped window in the second.  If you truly want to know the problem I would suggest providing screenshots that show the same information.    Off the top of my head, either your materials are different or your lighting settings are different.  I dont mean the directional light either I mean the actual settings under "Window->Rendering->lighting settings".

Comment: Can you add an image of the Directional Light settings and the material on the plane.

Comment: check the angle of the directional light. it does get brownish from lower angles, if set  to sun

Comment: @Eddge the cropping was only because I was cropping fast and thought that it did not matter. I checked everything and was identical to the tutorial, BUT, I went into the settings you mentioned, and pressed generate lightning (or whatever, I forgot the name, it is at the bottom). And for some reason it got solved, I mean, I can't go back to how it was though, so it was not like a toggle.

Comment: @akaBase added both directional light settings and material on the cube that was brownish before

Comment: @Max The image of your material has the material closed, but I was wanting to see its settings.

Comment: @akaBase, I realized that all I had to do was go into settings and press generate lightning. For some reason it was not. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Max Yea I was just pointing out it would be easier to troubleshoot if both images had identical information, something like this can be a setting on the renderer of the object, the material assigned to the object, the lights in the scene, or even the builtin in lighting settings.